# Wordpress news feed

Tags: html, wordpress, feed

So im trying to create a newsfeed in a static homepage, however I only want to show the title and date posted. I would have explored a widget, but I will later be tieing this news feed in with a slide show and I didn't want to be restricted.

What I have so far:

```
<div class="news-content">
 <?php query_posts('category_name=News'); ?>
  <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

     <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
     <?php twentythirteen_post_nav(); ?>

 <?php endwhile; else: ?>

 <?php endif; ?>
 <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
</div>
```

What ever help you can give will be appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [get_the_date()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_the_date) and [get_the_title()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title) should work. Your code should look something like:

```
<div class="news-content">
 <?php query_posts('category_name=News'); ?>
  <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

     <h1><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h1>
     <h2><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></h2>
    <?php twentythirteen_post_nav(); ?>

 <?php endwhile; else: ?>

 <?php endif; ?>
 <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than output `the_content()` with `get_template_part()`, you can just output each title with [the_title()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title), and each date with [the_date()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_date).